# Typescript generics for type A is a Class and B is a class that implements Interface<A>

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I would like to have a type safe register function that registers a WorkerOf with two arguments and two generic types so that consumers have to register a ClassA with the corresponding WorkerOfA.

```js
type Worker<Payload> = { exec: (payload: Payload) => Promise<void> };
type Constructor<Payload> = new (...args: any[]) => Payload;
type WorkerConstructor<Payload extends Constructor<Payload>> = new (
  ...args: any[]
) => Worker<Payload>;

function register<Payload extends Constructor<Payload>>(
  _pyd: Payload,
  _wkr: WorkerConstructor<Payload>
) {}

class PayloadOne {}
class PayloadTwo {}
class WorkerOne implements Worker<PayloadOne> {
  constructor() {}
  async exec(_payload: PayloadOne): Promise<void> {}
}

// Expected to work because WorkerOne implements Worker<PayloadOne>
register(PayloadOne, WorkerOne);
// Expected to fail because WorkerOne doesn't implements Worker<PayloadTwo>
register(PayloadTwo, WorkerOne);
```

In both cases I am getting the following typescript error:

`Argument of type 'typeof PayloadOne' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructor<typeof PayloadOne>'. Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'PayloadOne' but required in type 'typeof PayloadOne'.ts(2345)`

Comment: Can you articulate what `Payload extends Constructor<Payload >` is supposed to mean?  On the face of it means that `Payload ` is the type of a class constructor that constructs instances of `Payload `, so if `p` were a value of type `Payload `, you could write `const q: Payload  = new (new (new p())()) ()`.  Is that... what is that?

Comment: @jcalz, my goal with `Payload extends Constructor<Payload >` is to make sure that `_pyd` is a `class`. I don't really have any other constraint for that argument's type. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm *guessing* that you want `_pyd` to be of type `Constructor<T>` and for `_wkr` to be of type `WorkerConstructor<T>` for the same `T`.  But you haven't written that out and your constraints are confusing. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXKbDW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer, but I'm hoping you'll clear up the question first, by explaining your thought process and where you got that code from, and what it's supposed to mean.  And while you're at it, you might want to fix any typos (e.g., `WorkerOne doesn't implements Worker<PayloadOne>` seems like a typo somewhere)

Comment: @jcalz I edited the question, Thanks!!
Your approach is very close to what I want to achieve. However the compile error in your example can be bypassed by making the attributes in both classes the same.

I would like the compile error be based on the class name and not the class attributes.

Comment: @jcalz I guess that since this gets translated to JS the class name would not really matter since the attributes are the same. Your approach is the one man!
Thanks I will use it!!!

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying; yes, TypeScript considers two types with the same members to be the same type, even class instance types.  It's called [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system); if you want two classes to be seen as incompatible, they should have different members.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) of the form `T extends Constructor<T>` don't mean what you want them to mean.  If you need `T` to be a constructor type, `T extends Constructor<any>` would be sufficient.  Otherwise, `T extends Constructor<T>` means that `T` is a constructor type whose instances are themselves `T`. So it's a constructor that constructs constructors that construct constructors that construct constructors that... .

For the example you present, you don't even need `T extends Constructor<any>`.  Instead, let's let `T` be an arbitrary type, and have `register()`'s `_pyd` parameter be of type `Constructor<T>`, while `_wkr` is of type `WorkerConstructor<T>`.  That is, we would like the following code to be well-typed:

```
new _wkr().exec(new _pyd())
```

It looks like this:

```
type Worker<T> = { exec: (payload: T) => Promise<void> };
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type WorkerConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => Worker<T>;

function register<T>(
    _pyd: Constructor<T>,
    _wkr: WorkerConstructor<T>
) { }
```

That all compiles fine, and note that `T` is not constrained anywhere.  Let's make sure it works when you call `register()`:

```
class PayloadOne { a = 1 }
class PayloadTwo { b = 2 }    
class WorkerOne implements Worker<PayloadOne> {
    constructor() { }
    async exec(_payload: PayloadOne): Promise<void> { }
}

register(PayloadOne, WorkerOne); // okay
register(PayloadTwo, WorkerOne); // error
// Argument of type 'typeof PayloadTwo' is not assignable
// to parameter of type 'Constructor<PayloadOne>
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-c8WFp6LMAwBBKLuPmkQM9bL2ADkdggtDzkfkZNoBaQekqtBzzJ0kVAlJ5ZApcHo4Agk3oufzyAL5zlpVY5fFhHMQA)